# Can I bypass CORS preflight in a release version of an Ionic App?

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, preflight

The title pretty much says it all. I know I can bypass it in my browser with `--disable-web-security` (for chrome) but how does it work for releasing the app? I have no access to the server that is set to deny reverse proxies and only accepts GET requests not OPTIONS this leads to prefight issues. How can I work around this?

I've taken a look at these but they don't seem to answer the prefight from release workaround. Any Suggestions/workarounds?

http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Answer (score 0):

- Download Chrome cors extension
- Do not call a post call from the service, do that from a controller
- At the server side make sure you have a option route for every route you have available
- Perform a post request like this

  $http->post('you api', your_data)
  `.success(function(response) { ..}).error(function (error) {..})`

`.finally(function() {..});`

- Also get palanik/lumencors if your server runs with laravel

Answer (score 0):

You need not worry about CORS in a ionic app build, as in the recent ionic projects, the cordova plugin cordova-whitelist will already be put as part of the config.xml, so when you make a build, it handles the CORS issue by itself.